# RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR: syntax error at or near "-"

Tags: r

Folks,

I am connected to a postgre database through R using RPostgreSQL library.
the table name I am selecting from includes hyphen in the name of the schema.

I first create the connection

```
drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
pw <- {""}
conn <- dbConnect(drv, host="",
                  port="",
                  dbname="",
                  user="",
                  password= pw)



get_data_from_rs <- function(sql_cmd) {
  
  raw_data=dbGetQuery(conn,sql_cmd)
  return( raw_data )
  on.exit(dbDisconnect(conn))
}

Extract = "select * from Schema-name.table limit 1  "

Extract <- get_data_from_rs(Extract)
```

when I execute the code I receive an error as  due to  the "-" in the table name.

Can you please advice how to address this issue in R  Rstudio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often you have to quote names in a SQL query. If column names need to be capitalized then you have to quote them. It may actually not be your `-` that is the problem here.

Try:

```
Extract = 'select * from "Schema-name.table" limit 1;'
```

or

```
Extract = "select * from \"Schema-name.table\" limit 1;"
```

More info at [PostgreSQL: Documentation: 13:4.1.1](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS)

Comment: And if you get any say at all in the database design...recomend they use all lowercase and allowed characters. It is a pain to have to quote everything.

Comment: it worked- thanks man - wondering how did you get that from the documentation!

Comment: I just had this problem years ago and knew where to look.